# I am trying to run powershell script in c# . program runs successfully but does not show any output

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run powershell script in c# . program runs successfully but does not show any output.

```
try
{
    string fileName = "D:\\Script\\script.psm1";

    RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
    Runspace myRs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);
    myRs.Open();

    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(myRs);
    scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
    /*using (new Impersonator("myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword"))
    {
        using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
        {
            invoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");
        }
    } */
    Pipeline pipeline = myRs.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(fileName);
    //...
    pipeline.Invoke();
    var error = pipeline.Error.ReadToEnd();

    myRs.Close();
    string errors = "";
    if (error.Count >= 1)
    {

        foreach (var Error in error)
        {
            errors = errors + " " + Error.ToString();
        }
    }
    return errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is only checking for error output.  You typically get the "standard" output as the return value of the Invoke method e.g.

```
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
string output = "";
foreach (var result in results)
{
    output += result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't doing yourself any favors with that big `try {}` block wrapped around everything, as you can't see the exceptions that are happening.

You will need to run Visual Studio as a local administrator in order for "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" to work, and the final executable will also have that requirement since issuing that command requires access to a protected registry key.

The pipeline.Invoke() method returns a type of `Collection<PSObject>`.

```
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeLine.Invoke();
```

If your intent is to ignore the output of the pipeline and only look at errors, that is fine; but if there are no errors in the script, it would be normal not to see anything.

With the .psm1 file extension on the script, you will probably get null results. The proper extension should be `.ps1`. The `.psm1` extension is for modules that are stored in special locations on the file system and which are loaded automatically (in PowerShell 3.0+).

By default, 'Stop' type errors in PowerShell will generate an Exception in the C# program, so wrapping with try/catch is one way to see them.

```
Collection<PSObject> results = null;
try
{
    results = pipeline.Invoke();
    // results returned from PowerShell can be accessed here but may not
    // necessarily be valid since a 'Continue' error could have occurred
    // which would not generate an exception
}
catch (RuntimeException e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
}
```

You can test this by adding for example the following to your script.ps1:

```
throw "This is an error"
```

**Working Example:**

**Note:**
1. You will need to add a reference to System.Management.Automation.dll in order to run this code sample. If you are using Visual Studio, you can select Add Reference then the Browse... button and in the search box of the Browse dialog enter the name of the assembly and it will likely show up in the search results. If not you may need to download the .NET portion of the Windows SDK.
2. PowerShell scripts are disabled by default in Windows, and this is code that runs PowerShell scripts. There is plenty of information on the 'Net, but the standard way to enable scripts is to open a PowerShell command prompt as a local administrator and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` (if needed, Unrestricted can be used instead of RemoteSigned).
3. In some environments, you will need to unblock scripts downloaded from the Internet by right-clicking on the file in Windows Explorer, going to Properties, and clicking Unblock. If there is no Unblock button then the file is OK.
4. The first thing to try if you get access errors is to run Visual Studio and/or the executable as a local administrator. Please do not attempt to impersonate an administrator and embed a password in the executable. If you are in a corporate setting, group policy can be configured to allow PowerShell scripts to run. If you are at home, you should be a local administrator.

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PowerShell
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create and Open a Runspace
            string fileName = @"D:\script.ps1";
            RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace myRs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(config);
            myRs.Open();

            // Attempt to configure PowerShell so we can forcefully run a script.
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(myRs);
            scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force");

            Pipeline pipeline = myRs.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(fileName);

            Collection<PSObject> results = null;
            try
            {
                results = pipeline.Invoke();

                // Read standard output from the PowerShell script here...
                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Normal Output: " + item.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("PowerShell Script 'Stop' Error: " + e.Message);
            }

            myRs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting following exception at set execution policy statement .                             Exception:Caught: "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message:

Comment: The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. ] Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Comment: Do you want to change the execution policy?" (System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException)
A System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException was caught: "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message:

Comment: The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose you to the security risksdescribed in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?"
Time: 7/22/2015 11:42:09 PM
Thread:Pipeline Execution Thread[11032

Comment: I am unable to reproduce that exact error, but it sounds like the Set-ExecutionPolicy cmdlet is prompting for user input. There are a variety of things you can do, including but not limited to:
1. If you are at home using your personal computer, you can open a PowerShell command prompt as a local administrator and set the exectution policy to whatever you prefer. I myself like to set it like so: Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
2. If you are in a corporate setting you can discuss the creation of suitable group policy settings with the appropriate person(s).

Comment: 3. In the context of your application, you could either remove the command from your code and pursue a solution outside of C# (such as suggestion #1) or you could try adding -Force to the end of the command, such as Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

Comment: If your hosted script needs to prompt the user, you will need to implement the PowerShell host interface.  See PSHostUserInterface https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Now I am getting new exception Exception:Caught: "Unable to load DLL 'wldp.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" (System.DllNotFoundException)
A System.DllNotFoundException was caught: "Unable to load DLL 'wldp.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
Time: 8/9/2015 3:15:23 AM
Thread:<No Name>[11172]